# MBTiles performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, mapbox

I am working on an Android mapping application. 
 I am using MBTiles to store my tiles for offline viewing. All works great but performance degrades considerably as the db grows in size. Tiles vary in size but are generally around 6 kb in size and stored as blobs. I have replicated the schema used by Mapbox and others with indexes and all. The database is currently about 40 mb in size and reads take about 5 seconds. I have done quite a bit of research so far and have found nothing except that it should work. See [this SQLite page](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).
 What am I doing wrong? Is this an Android limitation?

Comment: *What* reads take 5 seconds? One tile? All tiles? What indexes do you have?

Comment: Retrieving one single tile from the database takes 5 seconds. Yes indexes have been added.

Comment: Replicated create scripts from here: https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/master/mbutil/util.py

Comment: And what is the slow query?

Comment: CL - MBTiles has two main tables; map and images. The map table contains a record for each tile (z,x,y) and is joined to its image via join in the tiles view. The reason for this separation is to conserve space since some tile are identical. Before image insert we generate the image id withUUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(tileBytes). If the id already exists in the image table we simply link to it if it doesn't exists a new image record is inserted. The query which is slow is retrieving a single tile (SELECT tile_data from tiles WHERE zoom_level = ? AND tile_column = ? AND tile_row = ?).

Comment: `tile_index` should optimize exactly this query. What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The table indices never got applied. The CREATE SQL sent via execSql contained two statements separated by a semi colon; one to create the table and another to create the associated index. Obviously only the first (CREATE TABLE) statement actually got executed so the second (CREATE INDEX) statement was never executed. I was able to find this out by using the sqlite3 util in the adb shell. Running .indices map didn't return anything. After altering the CREATE scripts to actually create indices VOILA! Super-Duper fast queries!

Comment: The guys over at Mapbox where kind enough to share their MBTiles schema. https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/blob/master/lib/schema.sql